# credentials stolen from forticlient

Tags: networking, security, vpn, fortigate

[image]

I connect to a network using forticlient. Tonight I used a different wifi connection to connect to the same network using forticlient but I started getting the wrong credentials error. Then I contacted the network administrator and he told me that I have entered wrong credentials several times because of which my account is locked. However, I didnt enter wrong credentials and every time network administrator would unlock my account, it started getting locked after every 1 minute. Something was trying to use my username to login, is it possible that my credentials might have been stolen through forticlient maybe because I was using a different wifi?

**Edit:** attaching an screenshot of the error I get. According to the network admin, something is trying to use my username to connect to the vpn and he keeps seeing requests from my username with bad credentials even when I am not trying to connect at all.

Comment: This might have occurred via Public Wireless which is generally considered to be unsafe. So you may have been hacked. More likely (my point of view) is that you made an inadvertent error entering credentials which stuck and then that caused he issue

Comment: @John No it wasnt a public network, it was a private network. What do you mean by  inadvertent error?

Comment: The network stream would have been encrypted (SSL VPN from Fortinet used by one of our clients) so it was not stolen that way. So likely not hacked or stolen at all. It may have asked for credentials for some reason and that is where we all make errors from time to time

Comment: Something is trying to authenticate against my account. Even if I dont try to connect to the VPN at all, the network admin still sees several requests with bad credentials from my account and it all started after I used a different internet connection. Makes me thinks something was stolen @John

Comment: If your computer has been compromised, then you may have a different and bigger issue than just Fortigate. You need to check email accounts, You should also change and significantly strengthen your Windows / Domain login credentials.

Comment: Is your username perhaps reasonably easy to guess? It could just be a random attack without actual knowledge.

Comment: @DanielB I dont think my username is too difficult to guess but I dont think it was a random attack because the problem started occurring exactly when I connected using a different internet connection over wifi. Normally I use a lan wire.